# WCF does not generate the properties

Tags: c#, wcf, asmx

I have a .NET 1.1 ASMX and want to use it in a client WinForms app.
If i go wit the old way and add it as a "WebRefrence" method then I will have access to two of its properties which are "url" and "UseDefaultCredentials"  and it works fine. 
But if I go with the new WCF way and add it as a ServiceReference I still have access to the methods of that ASMX but those two properties are missing.
what is the reason for that?

so for example in the old way ( adding WebReference) these codes are valid:

```
    TransferService transferService= new TransferService();
    transferService.Url = "http://something.asmx";
    transferService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    string[] machines = transferService.GetMachines();
```

But in the new way ( adding Service Reference )

```
    using(TransferServiceSoapClient transferServiceSoapClient = new TransferServiceSoapClient("TransferServiceSoap"))
    {
        transferServiceSoapClient.Url = "someUrl.asmx"; //Cannot resolve URL
        transferServiceSoapClient.GetMachines(new GetMachinesRequest());
        transferServiceSoapClient.Credentials = .... //  //Cannot resolve Credentials
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that there aren't errors while reference generating. Sometimes Visual Studio don't show error message, but show errors in "Error list".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because those are configured in the [endpoint in your app/web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731745.aspx) or [programatically](http://en.csharp-online.net/WCF_Essentials%E2%80%94Programmatic_Client_Configuration) if you prefer. More on configuring a [WCF client here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx).